# SymPy : Cancel out unnecessary variables and coefficients

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have an expression like :

```
b = IndexedBase('b')
k = IndexedBase('k')
w = IndexedBase('w')
r = IndexedBase('r')
z = IndexedBase('z')

i = symbols("i", cls=Idx)
omega = symbols("omega", cls=Idx)



e_p = (-k[i, omega]*r[i]/w[i] + k[i, omega]*r[i]/(b[omega]*w[i]))**b[omega]*k[i, omega]*r[i]/(-b[omega]*k[i, omega]*k[i, omega]**b[omega]*r[i]*z[omega]/w[i] + k[i, omega]*k[i, omega]**b[omega]*r[i]*z[omega]/w[i])
e_p = simplify(e_p)
print(type(e_p))
print(e_p)
```

```
<class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>

-(-(b[omega] - 1)*k[i, omega]*r[i]/(b[omega]*w[i]))**b[omega]*k[i, omega]**(-b[omega])*w[i]/((b[omega] - 1)*z[omega])
```

So `k[i, omega]` should be canceled out when I use `simplify()` function but do nothing. How can I get rid of unnecessary variables and coefficients?

Comment: Please give an example that is reproducible

Comment: What I want to reach if we expand paranthesis "(k[i,omega]**b[omega])" and "(k[i,omega]**-b[omega])" should cancel out each other.